# Density in sobolev spaces?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Is the Sobolev space $H_0^1(I)$ dense in $L^2(I)$, where $I\subset\mathbb R$?  If so, how do I prove it?

Comment: Is $H^1_0$ the space of al functions in the sobolev space $W^{1,2}$ with compact support?

Answer (score 2):

Smooth functions are dense in $L^2$, and you can pick an arbitrarily small (in whatever norm you like) smooth function with specified boundary values on $I$. So if $f_n \to f$, $f \in L^2$, you can replace $f_n$ with $f_n-g_n$, where say $\|g_n\|_{H^1} \leq \varepsilon$. So $f_n - g_n \to f$ in $L^2$, and $f_n-g_n$ is a smooth function that vanishes on the boundary of $I$ hence is in $H^1_0$.

Comment: first why did you choose a smooth function , i think we have to take a function of $L^2$ an then proove that there is a sequence $f_n$ in $H_0^1$ , checking $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^2$

Comment: Smooth functions are dense in $L^2$, period. So if $f \in L^2$. I can pick a sequence of smooth functions $f_n \to f$. Smooth functions are rather trivially in $H^1$ (provided by $I$ you mean the unit interval - if you mean something else, then one follows through the proof that smooth functions are dense to see that indeed smooth functions whose derivatives are also $L^2$ are also dense in $L^2$). Now we need to modify our setup so that the functions $f_n \to f$ vanish on the boundary. Hence the introduction of the $g_n$.

Comment: well what do you think about this suppose $I=[0,1]$ then we will have 
$C_0^\infty [0,1]\subset H_0^1[0,1]\subset L^2[0,1]$ then by density of $C_0^\infty [0,1]$ in $L^2[0,1]$ we can deduce the density of $H_0^1[0,1]$ in $L^2[0,1]$

Comment: the case that i need is $[0,1]$

Comment: Right, that's what I'm suggesting. The bit in my answer about $g_n$ is justifying why $C_0^\infty$ is dense, as opposed to the slightly more standard fact about $C^\infty$ being dense.

Comment: do you think so that this proof will be true when we the case of $\Omega$ is an open sunset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Everything we did is still valid there.